# Eclipse gradle plugin works, but library classes are not recognized

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

After days and days of hard work, I have my android project without errors in Eclipse.

I used build.gradle. Now, I can add library in that file writing "compile 'com.somelib.version'.

Now, I can type 'gradle clean' and 'gradle build'. These commands don't show errors. So, I think project added dependencies correctly. But I add Gson, or different library with gradle, how can I use it?

Eclipse give eror if I type 'import com.google.gson' (in this example). So, maybe I forgot a step before having dependencies working?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run these gradle commands:

```
cleanEclipseClasspath
eclipseClasspath
```

This worked for me when I had your issue.

Comment: sorry man :(. Aftter these 2 commands, I open again eclipse, but it cannot found com.thirpartylib.

Comment: have you installed the eclipse gradle plugin? if not you may wanna do so :) then go to the project you wanna update the resources, and use the gradle run with the three dots. if you type these two lines and run it, it should load the references you have set in your build.gradle.